# How to identify an Explorer Bar(Internet Explorer) is hidden or not?

Tags: c++, windows, internet-explorer, bho

I can make an Explorer bar show/hide using IWebBrowser2::ShowBrowserBar Method. I want to use a single button to toggle between Show/Hide. There is a parameter for ShowBrowserBar to set for Show/Hide. How will I get the status of the explore bar now?

Comment: Internet Explorer or Windows Explorer ?

Comment: ShowBrowserBar can only be used with IE

Comment: Isn't this functionality always accessible through the view->toolbars menu or through right-click on the bar? Why duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just check the value of pvaShow to get the status of the bar?
[IWebBrowser2::ShowBrowserBar Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

pvaShow
[in] A pointer to a VARIANT of type VT_BOOL that specifies whether the browser bar should be shown or hidden. If this is nonzero, the browser bar is shown. If this is zero, the browser bar is hidden.